# alguien me dice cual es el error en mi codigo?

Tags: python

Ese es mi codigo que hice para hackear contraseñas con Python:

```py
# password local bruteforce test
from random import *

user_pass = input("Enter your password")
password = ["a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,ñ,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z"]
guess = ""
while guess != user_pass:
    guess = ""
    for letter in range(len(user_pass)):
        guess_letter = password[randint(8, 25)]
        guess = str(guess_letter) + str(guess)
        print(guess)
print("Your password is:", guess)
```

Pero me dice que en la linea 10 del `randint(8, 25)` hay un error así:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\CENSORED\PycharmProjects\passwords\main.py", line 10, in
>
> ```
>  guess_letter = password[randint(8, 25)]
> ```
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Soy principiante en programación y no s'e el error, además todo está correcto como el tutorial.

Comment: No tienes una consola que te muestre los errores? o en que IDE o Editor estas trabajando?

Comment: El tamaño de tu arreglo es 1. No podrás acceder a un elemento con índice superior, como lo haces con tu randint, porque no existen

Comment: @TheVicShow entendi perfecto y me funciono gracias

Comment: @Amlizeaga un gusto poder ayudarte, si te fue de ayuda no olvides votar positivo la respuesta que te pareció mas completa

Answer (score 4):

Ahí te dice el error, eso quiere decir que estas poniendo un índex al arreglo password que sobrepasa el tamaño del arreglo.

Como podrás notar tu arreglo es de 1 posición, ya que las letras no están separadas por las comillas "" debes separar las letras por ejemplo `["a","b","c"....]` en lugar de `["a,b,c"]`

Es por eso que te esta dando un error, porque le estas diciendo que obtenga del arreglo password una posición entre 8 y 25 pero el tamaño de tu arreglo es 1

Te pongo un ejemplo para que te quede mas claro

Un arreglo de 3 posiciones seria algo como

`arreglo = ["Auto","Motocicleta","Autobús"]`

si quisiera obtener el valor motocicleta debo usar `arreglo[1]` sin embargo si le pongo `arreglo[3]` me va a dar el error de `Index out of range` porque mi arreglo es de 3 posiciones cabe destacar que los arreglos siempre empiezan desde 0, en este caso para obtener los datos debo usar las posiciones `0 1 2`, espero haberme explicado

De igual manera te dejo este [link](https://www.ecured.cu/Arreglos_(Inform%C3%A1tica)) que puede complementar tu conocimiento sobre los arreglos

Answer (score 0):

IndexError significa que estas accediendo a un elemento dentro de una lista que no existe. Por ejemplo digamos que tienes:

```
lista = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print(lista[0])  # Accedemos al primer elemento 
print(lista[1])  # Accedemos al segundo elemento
print(lista[2])  # Accedemos al tercer elemento
print(lista[3])  # Accedemos al cuarto elemento
```

Sin embargo el elemento [3] no existe, entonces nos hemos salido del rango de elementos que contiene la lista, y en consecuencia generara un error de tipo IndexError.

Otro detalle a abarcar, es que no es lo mismo ["A,B,C"] que contiene un elemento de tipo cadena, que ["A", "B", "C"] que contiene 3 elementos de tipo cadena. En tu caso tienes que dividir el abecedario en elementos, y no el abecedario completo en una cadena.